# Django InvalidQuery error with objects.raw()

Tags: python, ajax, django

InvalidQuery at /crms/cust/cust_popup/
Raw query must include the primary key

An error occurs. How do you handle it?

Request Method: POST
Request URL: http://192.168.91.170:55555/crms/cust/cust_popup/
    Django Version: 1.11.1
    Python Executable: /home/sweetyxyz/dev/web/myvenv/bin/python
    Python Version: 3.4.3

my Source code is .....

models.py

```
    class Cu_00(models.Model):
       cu_code = models.CharField(primary_key=True, unique=True, max_length=50)
       cu_nm = models.CharField(db_index=True, max_length=100)
       cu_addr = models.CharField(max_length=200,null=True)
       cu_memo = models.TextField(max_length=2000,null=True)
       cu_comp_yn = models.CharField(max_length=2,null=True) 
       cu_use_yn = models.CharField(max_length=2, null=True)
       cu_del_yn = models.CharField(max_length=2, default='N' )
       createDate = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
       def __str__(self):
           return self.cu_nm
```

urls.py

```
    ....

    url(r'^cust/cust_popup/$' , views_cu.isCustData, name='isCustData' ) ,

    .....
```

views.py

```
    def isCustData(req):

        if req.method == 'POST':
           cCust_nm = req.POST['cust_nm']
        else:
           cCust_nm = req.GET.get['cust_nm']

        cCust_nm = '%'+cCust_nm+'%'
        cDel_yn = 'N'

        cQuery = "select exists( select * from crmtotal_cu_00 where cu_nm like %s and cu_del_yn = %s )"
        events = Cu_00.objects.raw(cQuery, [cCust_nm, cDel_yn])
        context = {}

        events = serializers.serialize('json', events)
        context['is_taken'] = events

        return JsonResponse(data=serializers.serialize('json', events))
```

html source code

```
    ....
    <script>
    $("#cust_nm").change(function(){
      var cust_nm = $("#cust_nm").val() ;
      console.log(cust_nm) ;

      $.ajaxSetup({
        data: {csrfmiddlewaretoken: '{{ csrf_token }}' },
      });

      $.ajax({
              url: "{% url 'isCustData' %}",
              type : 'POST' ,
              data: {
                'cust_nm': cust_nm
              },
              dataType: 'json',
              success: function (data) {
                if (data.is_taken) {
                  alert("Cust Name is Found");
                }
              }
            });
       })
       </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

It doesn't make sense to use that query in a call to `raw()`.

```
cQuery = "select exists(
    select * from crmtotal_cu_00 where cu_nm like %s and cu_del_yn = %s
)"
```

You're selecting a true/false here, how is `raw()` supposed to turn that into an iterable of object instances?

You can recreate your query using Django's ORM without having to use SQL directly.

If you remove this line from your code:

```
cCust_nm = '%'+cCust_nm+'%'
```

Then this should give you what you want:

```
Cu_00.objects.filter(cu_nm__contains=cCust_nm, cu_del_yn='N').exists()
```

Depending on what `cu_nm` contains and what you're trying to select you may want to use `__icontains` instead of `__contains`. See the docs [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.11/ref/models/querysets/#contains)

`.exists()` returns a boolean, so you may need to adjust your serializer to account for that.